# Looking for a script to rename multiple files with charactares already in filename

Tags: file, batch-file

I have many files in many folders that I need to rename.
And example is
from cgs2016-09-05-05-40-34.xls
to cgs0905.xls

and 
from cgs2016-09-06-05-40-34
to cgs0906.xls

etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if there's also a file named _cgs201**5**-09-06-05-40-34_ in that folder? Or many others with the same date (at least same month and day) but with different times?

Comment: All files will have unique month and day characters, so no duplicates in that sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jamaz Try out the following code below on a sample of your files. Again please use it on a test sample of your files so it does not cause you issues if it makes a mistake. Thank you and please up-vote if this works for you.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Collect list of file names in current directory that have the .xls file extension. Output to text file.
dir /b "*.xls" >xls.txt
REM For loop examines the text file for individual file names.
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%# in (.\xls.txt) do ( 
REM SET variable "#" to equal "token"
    Set "token=%%#"
REM Extract the first 3 characters (year) from the file name and set is to variable "token"
    Set "tokenchar=!token:~0,3!"
REM Extract the month characters from the file name and set the variable as "tokenmonth"
    Set "tokenmonth=!token:~8,2!"
REM Extract the day characters from the file name and set the variable as "tokenday"
    Set "tokenday=!token:~11,2!"
    ren "%%#" "!tokenchar!!tokenmonth!!tokenday!.xls" 
    echo %%#

)
Pause
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks.
I'll tweak it for other folder with slightly different naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

not the best way, but works for your examples:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (*.xls) do (
  set "filename=%%x"
  ECHO ren "%%x" "!filename:~0,3!!filename:~8,2!!filename:~11,2!.xls"
)
```

remove the `ECHO` if output is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Stephan.
I put the code you suggested in a test.bat file ran it but no change to files....

Answer (score 0):

Because the last nineteen characters, *date and time stamp*, are more likely to be constant than the first three, *(especially over multiple folders)*, I'd change both the previous answers to cater for that rationale.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(Set _rf=C:\Users\jamaz\TestDir)
(Set _fe=xls)

If Not Exist "%_rf%\" Exit/B
For /R "%_rf%" %%I In (*.%_fe%) Do (Set "_fn=%%~nI"
    Echo=Ren "%%I" "!_fn:~,-19!!_fn:~-14,2!!_fn:~-11,2!%%~xI")
Timeout -1 1>Nul

EndLocal
Exit/B
```

As the OP was not clear about whether the code was for multiple same level folders or subfolders rooted from a single location, I went for the latter as the previous responses had already covered that.

**Change your chosen file path and extension on lines 4 and 5
If you are happy with the console output, remove `echo=` from line 10 and delete line 11**